# Rails 5 app deployed to heroku does not behave properly on mobile, but behaves properly with inspect on dev tools

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, mobile

I have a rails 5 app, which has a collapsible navbar for mobile, and collapsible nav sidebar. When I simulate a mobile environment by running heroku local and then inspect on chrome dev tools, it behaves properly: the navbar collapses to a small icon in the upper right corner, and the side bar collapses to a small icon on the left side of the screen, which is placed with css. However, when I open the app on my actual phone (an iphone 6), the navbar icon is in the wrong place (it has moved down a "row," where the navbar brand is on the left, and the collapse button is beneath it to the right, instead of parallel to it on the right), and the sidebar button does nothing when I press it.

Chrome dev tools do not show any errors.

I'm honestly not sure what the problem is - I figured it was some sort of asset-pipeline-precompile error, and I spent a while trying to get that to work, but precompiling assets both locally and remotely on heroku had no effect.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Here are some code files while may be of help:

app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TheLeagueBuilders</title>
        <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
        <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <%= render 'layouts/sidebar' %>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <%= render 'layouts/navigationBar' %>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <p class="notice"><%= notice %></p>
            <p class="alert"><%= alert %></p>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid col-sm-9 offset-sm-3 col-md-10 offset-md-2">
            <%= yield %>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss:

```
@import "welcome";
@import "font-awesome";
@import "bootstrap";


/*Font awesome icon*/
i {
    padding-top: 308px;
    z-index: 1001;
    position: fixed;
}
```

config/environments/production.rb:

```
Rails.application.configure do

  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS.
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  # config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

  # Do not fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed.
  config.assets.compile = false

  # `config.assets.precompile` and `config.assets.version` have moved to config/initializers/assets.rb

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server.
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = 'http://assets.example.com'


  config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [ :request_id ]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment)
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "TheLeagueBuilders_#{Rails.env}"
  config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  # Ignore bad email addresses and do not raise email delivery errors.
  # Set this to true and configure the email server for immediate delivery to raise delivery errors.
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require 'syslog/logger'
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')

  if ENV["RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT"].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

  # Emailing
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'fierce-woodland-66524.herokuapp.com' }

  #These settings are for the sending out email for active admin and consequently the   devise mailer
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port => '587',
    :authentication => :plain, 
    :user_name => ENV["SENDGRID_USERNAME"],
    :password => ENV["SENDGRID_PASSWORD"],
    :domain => 'heroku.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true 
  }
end
```

And the some of the sidebar code:

```
<div class="row">
    <% if user_signed_in? %>

        <div class="hidden-md-up">
            <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right fa-2x" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample" aria-hidden="true"></i> <!--Rename href, aria-controls-->
        </div>

        <!--Use CSS instead of style!-->
        <nav class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 bg-faded" id="collapseExample" style="position:fixed;top:51px;bottom:0px;padding:20px;z-index:1000;">
            <div class="">
                <ul class="navbar-nav">
                    .............
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Any help would be truly truly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Any chance you could share the heroku url?

Comment: Certainly: it is fierce-woodland-66524.herokuapp.com I've updated it so the navbar and sidebar appear even if you aren't logged in. I'm sorry I didn't get to this sooner, I've been sick the past few days